# Projection on a MongoDb Query using Spring data and QueryDSL

Tags: spring, mongodb, projection, spring-data

I have a Spring MVC/Spring Data / Mongo DB application.
I have setted up my environement according the the spring data documentation and my repositories work fine (I can execute queries with predicates)

I was wondering if it was possible to execute a type safe query (using Spring Data and QueryDSL) while making a projection (I want only a few fields of a very big document).

The QueryDSL documentation gives an example for Hibernate but states it can be done in all modules [QueryDSL Documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03.html) (but I haven't been able to find out how to do it with Mongo)

here's the code snippet for hibernate

```
class CustomerDTO {

  @QueryProjection
  public CustomerDTO(long id, String name){
     ...
 }

 QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
 JPQLQuery query = new HibernateQuery(session);
 List<CustomerDTO> dtos = qry.from(customer).list(new QCustomerDTO(customer.id,    customer.name));
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported. Feel free to add a ticket for it into our [Issue tracker](https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues).

The Lucene and Mongodb modules of Querydsl support only direct projections from the query root, but for custom projections something could be figured out.

Comment: Issue [created](https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/205), thank you for the advice.

Comment: Just got the email indicating that this functionality is now implemented in the QueryDSL framework! great news!!

Comment: Is it supported with Morphia only ? We use Spring data.

Comment: It would be nice if we had another implementation for Spring Data framework. Because I had to drop Morphia for some reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/41393517/413032

Answer (score 0):

I've just built a projection like this:

```
Criteria c1 = Criteria.where("field.name").is("val")
Criteria projection = Criteria.where("field").is(1)
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(c1.getCriteriaObject(), projection.getCriteriaObject())
```

Comment: That's not type safe nor you are using the QueryDSL framework, you are using the standard Spring Data objects.