# Is it yet possible to use QueryDSL in a Spring Data Mongo repository with projections?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

We are using Spring Data Mongo and more specifically extended our repository from `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`. The queries with predicates are no problem but how can we use projection in this context?

I only found a similar question with this topic some years ago:
[Projection on a MongoDb Query using Spring data and QueryDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11688807/1770433)

Does anybody know the current state of projections in conjunction with QueryDSL for Spring Data Mongo repositories?

Comment: See the ticket https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/205

Comment: Hm, I see that QueryDSL is able to fulfill this request, but how to achieve this with Spring Data Mongo?